# Integrating an Arduino to a commercial product

Tags: arduino, pcb, pcb-design

We are developing a product which we hope to introduce to the market soon. It has an Atmel microcontroller and some other circuitry. Recently we thought of directly using an Arduino BLE33 on the PCB without building the microcontroller on our PCB. This gives us the advantage of a easily swappable micro controller in case one fries. This costs a bit more.
But other than that what will be the pros and cons of this approach.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a bare Atmel? You would save dozens of dollars per product. It's not that difficult to swap microcontrollers to begin with. If you find yourself needing to do it a lot, invest the money into a soldering tip specialized for the MCU package, hot tweezers, or hot air.

Comment: A MCU that is fried, indicate a poor design.

Comment: BLE33 "original" is a significant cost. Chinese "clones" (legitimate) are avaialble from many sources (many on eg Ali-Express) at 10%-20% in cost. Quality will vary and you'd need to establish a reliable supplier - both in quality and ongoing supply. | You lose some flexibility in layout and features but this is liable to be acceptable.

Comment: BLE33 is not Atmel, is 3.3 V, has BLE, IMU and RGB LED

Comment: @MatsKarlsson has a very good point here that should not be overlooked at all. If this product has even the slightest chance of the microcontroller frying, this product is clearly not ready for the market. I highly suggest you go back and redesign the product and figure out what the issue is. Remember, if you thought of every way to break your product, the consumer has already thought of 10 more.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend it the hard way. It is cheaper for production and the PCB doesn't consume so much power. But with WiFi or Bluetooth a pre-made board can make your life much easier. Because then you need no certification to comply with laws. Or it is easier.
And for example, if a microprocessor is only available in BGA it can be then very expensive.
But if you want to go to real mass production then Arduino can not sell you enough boards.
This is a very important decision for you. **Don't do what other people are saying. Make your decision.**

**So it depends on your application!**